# How to remove mannequin hands and neck from image of a t-shirt?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image of a mannequin wearing a t-shirt in a green background. My end goal is to remove the mannequin hands and half neck from the image.

I am able to remove the green background perfectly, but don't understand how should I proceed to remove the neck and hands in the image which are generally white coloured.

My image after removing the background is like this:

[image: image two]

From here I need to remove the head and hands which are white (not in this image, but they are). I was thinking that I could check the range of the white and remove but as you can see in this image, the shirt itself can be white or partly white and hence fall in between the removing range of the color.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is of skin detection and it can't be solved by using simple techniques for all the reasons that you mentioned. It's an involved problem and some possible solutions are -

- [Deep Learning based solution](https://github.com/WillBrennan/SemanticSegmentation)
- [More of a classical approach by using semantic segmentation](https://github.com/Jeanvit/PySkinDetection)

Comment: Thank you, but I have a mannequin, and I need to remove the skin that is whitish (general mannequin color), I don't think the simple skin detection would work with that. What do you say?

Comment: The semantic segmentation based algorithm should still work with some slight tweaking, the deep learning approach might work out-of-the box because it's likely also looking at the shape of the objects surrounding the skin (shape of hands, head etc). But if it doesn't, you need to re-train it with the kind of data you would want it to recognize.